# reading firestore array field on Flutter list builder

Tags: arrays, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Reading Firestore array field on a Flutter list builder. Here the code I tried.
But I got this error message :

[image]

please help!

```
class _ListClients2 extends State<ListClients2> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder(
      future: getList(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        } else {
          return Center(
            child: ListView.builder(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Center(
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(snapshot.data[index].data
                          .toString()), //snapshot data should dispaly in this text field
                    ),
                  );
                }),
          );
        }
      }
```

```
  Future<List<dynamic>> getList() async {
    var firestore = Firestore.instance;

    DocumentReference docRef =
        firestore.collection('admin_users').document(idUser);

   
    return docRef.get().then((datasnapshot) {
      if (datasnapshot.exists) {
        List<dynamic> info = datasnapshot.data['clients'].toList();
        print('#');
        print(info); 
        print(info.length); 
        return info;
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Most likely your `snapshot.data[index]` is not returning anything. To not fail on that, use `?.`. So `snapshot.data[index]?.data?.toString()`.

Comment: thanks, frank, but still have the same error message

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide `data()['clients']` not `data['clients']` to get value from document.

```
List<dynamic> info = datasnapshot.data()['clients'].toList();
```

Comment: thanks, Harsha for your answer, I tried to add the brackets but  got  a syntax error  :(, any idea?

Comment: please guys any help? also is there a way to get full documentation for flutter and firebase?

Comment: still did not find any solution to this I am really stuck, is there a way to have support from flutter dev team on this?

Comment: Can you update your question with the new error you facing? Will try to help you out.

Comment: hello harsha ,  sorry but what do you mean by  update, cuz I am still stuck in with the same problem,

Comment: I should add that when I print the Var INFO where I store the list I get the correct list values displayed in the console but it doesn't work for the listview

Answer (score 0):

The "NoSuchMethodErrorr: Class" error most of the times mean that you are trying to read a data type instead of the data type you are sending. So, it seems like you are expecting the "clients" part of the datasnapshot to be a list but it's apparently a string.

I would recommend you to double check the current datasnapshot text and probably you have something like

```
"clients": "something here"
```

instead of

```
"clients": [...]
```